# Polygon with smooth corners runtime in unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a polygon shape as an array of Vector3 points. I want to get same array but with smooth corners. Is there a simple solution that works out the box?

Comment: Is your shape 2D, 3D with points Z coordinate set to 0 or generally speaking 3D?

Comment: No.  Unity merely draws whatever points/mesh you've imported/created. http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/153117/smoothing-edges-of-a-mesh.html.

Comment: RCYR, it's 3d with Z set to 0

Comment: MuckyD, it is not about drawing it's about math stuff to change array, like beizer splines or sort of.